# Can't debug Windows Service if it's installed by Visual Studio Installer

Tags: c#, wcf, debugging, windows-services, windows-installer

I've been debugging for a quite while the Windows Service I've been working with without any noticeable problems. I used to install it thourgh the `installutil` command and I was able to debug it (followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-debug-windows-service-applications) MSDN tutorial).

Deploying the service to the production server meant so much pain in order to pack all dependencies, so I was encouraged to deploy it through some kind of installer.

Which one? "Quick and dirty" solution: [Visual Studio installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/2kt85ked(v%3Dvs.100))

Everything is running fine until the point I needed to debug the installed server as I have been doing until now. I attach the Windows Service process but the debugger isn't stopping at my breakpoint.

What am I exactly missing?

Answer (score 1):

While I was writing the question, I asked myself how did I configured the build properties. For my surprise, it was set to `release`.

I changed it to `debug`, uninstalled the service, installed it again and I finally had my service being debugged.

[image]

Bear in mind I always installed the service right-clicking on the project's name and clicking into "install". Seems this takes the installer placed on the specified build config.
[image]

Thing is this service is supposed to be installed uniquely on a production server. I was supposed to deploy always the release version in order to be completely clean and optimised, so I guess I will have to keep swapping this option, at least for my own workspace.

And yes, my `installutil` was pointing to **debug build**.